# Frequent refresh of materialized view in Oracle

Tags: oracle, query-optimization, materialized-views

We are optimizing performance and want to create the materialized view (several millions of records) built on joins of handful of tables. This view will be used in order to show users documents in folders with delay not more than several (3-5) seconds.

I suppose it must be out-of-place MV with refresh interval several seconds.

Is it acceptable solution from database point of view?

The view will be something like this:

```
 SELECT *
   FROM documents this_
        LEFT OUTER JOIN account_statements this_1_
           ON this_.Id = this_1_.FK_Document
        LEFT OUTER JOIN contracts this_2_ ON this_.Id = this_2_.FK_Document
        LEFT OUTER JOIN pension_agreements this_3_
           ON this_.Id = this_3_.FK_Contract
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dead this_4_ ON this_.Id = this_4_.FK_Document
        LEFT OUTER JOIN pay_orders this_5_ ON this_.Id = this_5_.FK_Document
        LEFT OUTER JOIN pay_registers this_6_
           ON this_.Id = this_6_.FK_Document
        LEFT OUTER JOIN pocards this_7_ ON this_.Id = this_7_.FK_Document
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ransom_agreements this_8_
           ON this_.Id = this_8_.FK_Document
        LEFT OUTER JOIN successor_statements this_9_
           ON this_.Id = this_9_.FK_Document
        INNER JOIN document_treenodes treenodes14_
           ON this_.Id = treenodes14_.fk_document
        INNER JOIN treenodes treenode2_
           ON treenodes14_.fk_treenode = treenode2_.Id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN registration_cards regcard1_
           ON this_.fk_registration_card = regcard1_.Id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN employees todirectem12_
           ON regcard1_.to_direct = todirectem12_.Id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN REG_CARD_STATUSES regcardsta11_
           ON regcard1_.status = regcardsta11_.Id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN filestorages filestorag10_
           ON this_.fk_file = filestorag10_.Id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN actions holdaction4_
           ON this_.fk_hold = holdaction4_.Id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN employees holdemploy5_
           ON holdaction4_.fk_operator = holdemploy5_.Id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN actions doneaction6_
           ON this_.fk_done = doneaction6_.Id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN employees doneemploy7_
           ON doneaction6_.fk_operator = doneemploy7_.Id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN actions signaction8_
           ON this_.fk_signed = signaction8_.Id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN employees signemploy9_
           ON signaction8_.fk_operator = signemploy9_.Id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN actions scanaction3_
           ON this_.fk_scan = scanaction3_.Id
```

**UPDATE**
The bottleneck is in the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM documents this_
  INNER JOIN document_treenodes treenodes14_ ON this_.Id = treenodes14_.fk_document
  INNER JOIN treenodes treenode2_ ON treenodes14_.fk_treenode = treenode2_.Id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN registration_cards regcard1_ ON this_.fk_registration_card = regcard1_.Id
WHERE (
        regcard1_.status IS NULL OR
        (
          NOT (
            regcard1_.status = 3 /* :p0 */)
          AND
          NOT (
            regcard1_.status = 4 /* :p1 */)
        )
      )
      AND
      this_.fk_deleted IS NULL AND
      (
        this_.isdelete IS NULL OR
        this_.isdelete = 0 /* :p2 */)
      AND
      treenode2_.Id = 1235 /* :p3 */ AND
      this_.fk_done IS NULL AND
      (
        regcard1_.status IS NULL OR
        NOT (
          regcard1_.status = 1 /* :p4 */)
      )
   ORDER BY this_.Id DESC
   OFFSET 0 ROWS
   FETCH FIRST 50 /* :p5 */ ROWS ONLY
      treenode2_.Id = 1235 /* :p3 */ AND
      this_.fk_done IS NULL AND
      (
        regcard1_.status IS NULL OR
        NOT (
          regcard1_.status = 1 /* :p4 */)
      )
ORDER BY this_.Id DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH FIRST 50 /* :p5 */ ROWS ONLY
```

And the plan is:

Plan hash value: 3579815467

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                  | Name                 | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT           |                      |   105K|    85M|       | 50518   (1)| 00:00:04 |
|*  1 |  VIEW                      |                      |   105K|    85M|       | 50518   (1)| 00:00:04 |
|*  2 |   WINDOW SORT PUSHED RANK  |                      |   105K|    13M|    14M| 50518   (1)| 00:00:04 |
|*  3 |    HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER   |                      |   105K|    13M|       | 48503   (1)| 00:00:04 |
|   4 |     INDEX FULL SCAN        | REG_CARD_STATUSES_PK |     4 |    12 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |     FILTER                 |                      |       |       |       |            |          |
|*  6 |      HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER |                      |   105K|    13M|  4048K| 48502   (1)| 00:00:04 |
|   7 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL    | REGISTRATION_CARDS   | 84317 |  3046K|       |   171   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|*  8 |       HASH JOIN            |                      |   183K|    17M|  3936K| 47339   (1)| 00:00:04 |
|*  9 |        INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| DOCUMENT_TREENODE_PK |   183K|  1788K|       |  1872   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|* 10 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL   | DOCUMENTS            |  5064K|   425M|       | 24635   (2)| 00:00:02 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("from$_subquery$_010"."rowlimit_$$_rownumber"<=0+50 AND 
              "from$_subquery$_010"."rowlimit_$$_rownumber">0)
   2 - filter(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY INTERNAL_FUNCTION("THIS_"."ID") DESC )<=0+50)
   3 - access("REGCARD1_"."STATUS"="REGCARDSTA11_"."ID"(+))
   5 - filter(("REGCARD1_"."STATUS" IS NULL OR "REGCARD1_"."STATUS"<>3 AND 
              "REGCARD1_"."STATUS"<>4) AND ("REGCARD1_"."STATUS" IS NULL OR "REGCARD1_"."STATUS"<>1))
   6 - access("THIS_"."FK_REGISTRATION_CARD"="REGCARD1_"."ID"(+))
   8 - access("THIS_"."ID"="TREENODES14_"."FK_DOCUMENT")
   9 - filter("TREENODES14_"."FK_TREENODE"=1235)
  10 - filter("THIS_"."FK_DONE" IS NULL AND ("THIS_"."ISDELETE"=0 OR "THIS_"."ISDELETE" IS NULL) 
              AND "THIS_"."FK_DELETED" IS NULL)
```

Comment: How long does the query take to run?

Comment: Also, try to only select the columns you really need instead of `*`, especially if you plan on materializing this view!

Comment: @slambeth From 15 to 45 seconds for now. Users cant wait so long...

Comment: @deroby Thanks, but asterisk is already replaced with certain column names. Due to there are many columns I replaced them with asterisk in the question.

Comment: I'm guessing the user only asks for a smallish subset of the view; e.g. `WHERE _this.document_id = 4875` or something along those lines. If so, half a minute seems like an unwarranted long time to run this. Does EXPLAIN give any hints towards what the bottleneck might be? From what I can tell this looks like a very straight forward normalized data model, every RDBMS should zip through it within the blink of an eye.

Comment: @deroby Initially I thought that I'll get rid of this problem via materialized view and that's why my initial select query was simplified a bit. But if there is another solution I'll be glad if you could help me. :) 
I'll update the question.

Comment: I'm not very versed in Oracle (ask me anything MSSQL =) but if those Time Column indicates seconds, then I'm under the impression that you're 'losing' most time in sorting the output? Paginating can really hurt server-side but  maybe someone knows ways around that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the liberty of 'reformatting' your query (BTW: I think there is a bit of a copy-paste error in there, some parts look doubled near the end)

The 'layout' will have zero effect on the actual execution times, but it makes it easier *for me* to understand what you're doing (simply because I'm used to my own style, I'm not claiming it's better, it's simply what *I* am used to)

Anyway, if I understood correctly and didn't mess up the brackets, then this should be equivalent to your query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM documents this_
 INNER JOIN document_treenodes treenodes14_ 
         ON treenodes14_.fk_document = this_.Id
 INNER JOIN treenodes treenode2_ 
         ON treenode2_.Id = treenodes14_.fk_treenode
        AND treenode2_.Id = 1235 /* :p3 */ 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN registration_cards regcard1_ 
               ON regcard1_.Id = this_.fk_registration_card 

 WHERE this_.fk_deleted IS NULL 
   AND this_.fk_done IS NULL 
   AND ( 
          this_.isdelete IS NULL OR this_.isdelete = 0 /* :p2 */
       )
   AND ( 
          regcard1_.status IS NULL OR regcard1_.status NOT IN (3 /* :p0 */, 4 /* :p1 */, 1 /* :p4 */) 
       )

 ORDER BY this_.Id DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS
 FETCH FIRST 50 /* :p5 */ ROWS ONLY
```

I doubt this change will make much difference, but it might change the way the system approaches steps 8 & 9 in the current plan. Worth a try =)

Anyway, what I 'learned' from the query is that you seem to want all records that have no matching [registration_cards] record, but if there are, then they should not have status 3, 4 or 1 (:p0, :p1, :p4 respectively).
=> wouldn't this be equivalent to saying that you want all [documents] records for which there is no matching [registration_cards] record that has status 3, 4 or 1?

```
SELECT *
  FROM documents this_
 INNER JOIN document_treenodes treenodes14_ 
         ON treenodes14_.fk_document = this_.Id
 INNER JOIN treenodes treenode2_ 
         ON treenode2_.Id = treenodes14_.fk_treenode
        AND treenode2_.Id = 1235 /* :p3 */ 

 WHERE this_.fk_deleted IS NULL 
   AND this_.fk_done IS NULL 
   AND ( 
         this_.isdelete IS NULL OR this_.isdelete = 0 /* :p2 */
       )
   AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                      FROM registration_cards regcard1_ 
                     WHERE regcard1_.Id = this_.fk_registration_card 
                       AND regcard1_.status IN (3 /* :p0 */, 4 /* :p1 */, 1 /* :p4 */) )

 ORDER BY this_.Id DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS
 FETCH FIRST 50 /* :p5 */ ROWS ONLY
```

Assuming [registration_card].Id is the PK of the table, or there is a covering index on the status and Id field, this might be slightly faster. Like I said before, I'm under the impression most of the time is lost in sorting the result-set but then again I might be totally misinterpreting the explain plan. Googling around actually seems to inform me that [the explain plan is but guesswork and not 'the real deal'](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1434984500346471382).... sigh, at times I really pity you poor Oracle users =P

Comment: Thank you for your help. We solved the performance issues we had by rewriting queries completely.